# Как отловить event в Lightbox Uikit?

Tags: javascript, uikit

Здравствуйте!
Есть компонент lightbox в фреймворке Uikit,
https://getuikit.com/docs/lightbox
не совсем понятно как слушать события( Нужно при показе/перелистывание слайдера динамически ставить autofocus на картинку чтобы был доступен скрол со стрелок клавиатуры).
Cпасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример:

```
var $triggerElement = $('.uk-lightbox.uk-open');

// fire events
$(document).on('beforeshow', $triggerElement, function() {
  UIkit.notification({
    message: 'Beforeshow Lighbox',
    status: 'success',
    pos: 'top-right',
    timeout: 1000
  });

});
```